# parse error - Drupal 8

Tags: php, parse-platform, syntax, drupal-8

I have a Drupal site that is uploaded to Hostgator, I have uploaded nearly 16.000 files and the database. The server is running PHP7.

I have changed the settings.php files to the correct database information

But I get this error message:

Warning: require() [function.require]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead in /home1/danielk/public_html/goldberg.nu/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php on line 78

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '{' in /home1/danielk/public_html/goldberg.nu/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php on line 78[functions.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SuRb.png)

I am no developer at all, so I have no understanding on the above.
Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Has the site worked on another server - localhost, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Write in this manner 
function ($resource = '' , array $options) {}